# Android Studio dependency Version conflict gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a conflict with my dependencies, and no matter which version I try that it recommends me, it doesn't solve the issue. Looking around did no help so this is my last resort. Here is my error;

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.

My Gradle;

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

---

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Make sure all the firebase and gms libs have the same version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin

You should use **SAME** versions of **`FIREBASE`** & **`GMS`** .

Use ***`11.0.4`*** .

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'
```

Finally **Clean-Rebuild-Run** .

Comment: This solved my issue. I would have voted +1 for the answer, but I don't have enough popularity. Is there a reason why they all have to be the same versions? I feel like I missed something in the documentation, or experts in tutorials never ever specify that type of info.

Comment: @EdwardBenedict Glad to hear . You can accept this answer . Click on Right Sign

Answer (score 1):

You should remove following line from gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'
```

Firebase dependencies must have same version

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'
```

Comment: because your answer makes no sense. Deleting the project will also solve the error. Suggesting to remove the code that produces an error is not a solution

Comment: play services already added as a plugin and in dependencies also having play services thats why getting conflit

Comment: plugin and dependency is not the same. You must have both

Comment: If you have apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' then this is no need compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'

Comment: the plugin is required for firebase libs, the compile is required for play-services lib

Comment: question is related to both fcm and google play services, if project only contains google play services then i agree with the above link provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
```

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'`

Change these dependency with this version.